Error on converting Json data to QR code using JS library
I'm trying to convert JSON data into a QR code, so when a user scans it, the JSON data should be displayed. I've been using the jquery.qrcode.min.js library for this. Here's an example of the JSON data format:
{"id":"4444455551223","tableid":"2222221111111444","areacode":"A0010","catid":"QWAAD"}
p.s id,tableid,areacode,catid these are fetched dynamically from url parameter
e.g www.demo.com?id=4444455551223&tableid=2222221111111444&areacode=A0010&catid=QWAAD
However, the issue I'm facing is that when I scan the generated QR code with a mobile device, it only shows "4444455551223" as the result, rather than displaying the entire JSON data. Any ideas on how to solve this?
Code used to generate QR code.
          jQuery('#output').qrcode( {  


            const queryString = window.location.search;
      
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

            const id = urlParams.get('id').toString();

            const  tableid = urlParams.get('tableid').toString();

            const  areacode = urlParams.get('areacode').toString();

            const  catid = urlParams.get('catid').toString();

            var myJSON ={"id":"'+id+'","tableid":"'+tableid+'","areacode":"'+areacode+'","catid":"'+catid+"}';


            // render method: 'canvas', 'image' or 'div'
            //render: 'canvas',

            // version range somewhere in 1 .. 40
            minVersion: 1,
            maxVersion: 40,

            // error correction level: 'L', 'M', 'Q' or 'H'
            ecLevel: 'Q',

            // offset in pixel if drawn onto existing canvas
            left: 0,
            top: 0,

            // size in pixel
            size: 500,

            // code color or image element
            fill: '#000',


            // corner radius relative to module width: 0.0 .. 0.5
            radius: 0,

            // quiet zone in modules
            quiet: 0,
           text: myJSON
 
        } );

        });


Please show us your code so that we can try to help you.
It's impossible to see what your code is doing wrong, if you do not show us your code.

@RayWallace I have updated with the code

I don't know how you got your code to give you even one value in the QR code. Your code as is, was not runnable at all for me.
There were two major problems:

Your const and var definitions need to be moved out of the .qrcode() function body.
Setting your myJSON was all wrong. You did not end up with any of your data in it.

Here is the edited code that worked for me:
// NOTE Your const a var definitions need to be moved out of the .qrcode() function body

const queryString = window.location.search;

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

// NOTE You do not need the .toString(), the paramaters are already strings
const id = urlParams.get('id').toString();

const  tableid = urlParams.get('tableid').toString();

const  areacode = urlParams.get('areacode').toString();

const  catid = urlParams.get('catid').toString();


// NOTE This line has a misplace ' at the end
// NOTE Even then it does not give you anything useful
//   var myJSON={"id":"'+id+'","tableid":"'+tableid+'","areacode":"'+areacode+'","catid":"'+catid+"}';
var myJSON = JSON.stringify( {id, tableid, areacode, catid} )

jQuery('#output').qrcode( {
  // version range somewhere in 1 .. 40
  minVersion: 1,
  maxVersion: 40,

  // error correction level: 'L', 'M', 'Q' or 'H'
  ecLevel: 'Q',

  // offset in pixel if drawn onto existing canvas
  left: 0,
  top: 0,

  // size in pixel
  size: 500,

  // code color or image element
  fill: '#000',

  // corner radius relative to module width: 0.0 .. 0.5
  radius: 0,

  // quiet zone in modules
  quiet: 0,
  text: myJSON

} );

// NOTE This is an extraneous line
// });


As per your suggestion i tried at my end, but still the problem exists. Mobile device is reading as phonenumber instead of json data.

Very odd. Worked perfect for me.  ...  Can you post the resulting QR code image?

When I ran my version of the code, it displayed this QR code: https://ibb.co/YysZCxX    ...   When I scan it I get this result:   {"id":"4444455551223","tableid":"2222221111111444","areacode":"A0010","catid":"QWAAD"}

When I put large number like 4444455551223 its working. What i was using was 8 digit number as ID. Please can you check with 8 digits at your end also.

I just removed the 4444 from the beginning of the id and it works as well. I do not see anything in the code that would be affected by the length of the numbers. To be clear, I used:   ....    www.demo.com/?id=55551223&tableid=2222221111111444&areacode=A0010&catid=QWAAD

My device is IOS. When I scanned in my friends android phone its working.
So i believe something related to IOS
